# Save Async/Await response on a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to understand async calls using async/await and try/catch.

In the example below, how can I save my successful response to a variable that can be utilized throughout the rest of the code?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const users = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

const asyncExample = async () =>{
    try {
        const data = await axios(users);
        console.log(data); //200
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

//Save response on a variable
const globalData = asyncExample(); 
console.log(globalData) //Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: `globalData` shouldn't be `undefined`, it should be a `Promise` (which is the only thing an async function can return).

Comment: Note that `async`/`await` are **not** "ecmascript-6" (properly: ECMAScript 2015). They were added in ES2017, two years later.

Comment: But note that even if you wait for the promise to resolve, its resolution value will be `undefined`. To make it something else, you need `return` in your `asyncExample` function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited the question, apologies for leaving the old comment saying 'undefined'. How would you go about saving the response into a variable that can be used elsewhere in the scope of the same file?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1: Return something from your `asyncExample` function

```
const asyncExample = async () => {
  const result = await axios(users)

  return result
}
```

2: Call that function and handle its returned `Promise`:

> The `;(async...` is an IFFE [(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression). You need it to perform top-level await. It's not part of this answer so don't get confused.

```
;(async () => {
  const users = await asyncExample()
  console.log(users)
})()
```

Here's why should you handle it like this:

- You can't do top-level `await` (there's [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) for it though);
  `await` must exist within an `async` function.

However I must point out that your original example doesn't need `async/await`
at all; Since `axios` already returns a `Promise` you can simply do:

```
const asyncExample = () => {
  return axios(users)
}

const users = await asyncExample()
```

Comment: Or if you want `async`/`await` all the way down: https://pastebin.com/i6FPUs2y (but it's important that **all** of the code in that wrapper is in `try`/`catch` -- without one, you set yourself up for "Unhandled rejection" errors).

Comment: Yes -- but incorrectly. The `try`/`catch` (or using `.catch` on the result) is not optional.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, that's great! How would I achieve the same result using try/catch?

Comment: You don't need a `try/catch` within your `asyncExample` function. If it fails, the top-level `.catch()` handler will be triggered with the appropriate error.

Comment: This doesn't save the returned value to a variable though. This just console logs the returned value which is not what the question was about.

Comment: @DavidA.French Well, I supposed what I meant a year ago was to put your "main" code within the `.then` callback. FWIW I'd advise the OP to simply accept another answer instead of mine since the IIFE tricks are far more succint and appropriate in regards to the OP.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Thank you for responding. I've actually been trying to figure out how to do what this question is asking about for like 5 hours. I know the IIFE trick etc, but the variable created with that trick only has scope for the IIFE and I really need to find some way of exporting that return value into a variable with global scope. I'm trying to take data I have grabbed using an async fetch and inject it into the data field of a JSON object being used by ChartJS.

Comment: @DavidA.French Why don't you wrap all your "main" app code in an async IIFE and get it over with? It's not an uncommon pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually done a similar thing before. I probably should, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't just using it as a crutch. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: what is this little ; before (async .. ?

Comment: @danielassayag It avoids this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186265/iife-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function/53186477#53186477

Answer (score 6):

`try..catch` creates a new block scope. Use `let` to define `data` before `try..catch` instead of `const`, `return` `data` from `asyncExample` function call

```js
(async() => {

  const users = 123;

  const asyncExample = async() => {
    let data;
    try {
      data = await Promise.resolve(users);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return data;
  };

  //Save response on a variable
  const globalData = await asyncExample();
  console.log(globalData);
  // return globalData;
})();
```

Comment: @guest271314 does that mean that anything else that I'd want to do with global data would have to be done within the (async() => { })(); scope?

Comment: @tonkihonks13 No, you can uncomment `//return globalData`, chain `.then()` to the async arrow function and perform tasks with the passed argument at the function passed to `.then()`

Comment: Thanks, I had this issue. I was looping an array while setting a local variable and when that variable was read it was only read as the first value it was set. I used let and it's fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue with you and found this post. After 2 days of trying I finally found a simple solution.
According to [the document of JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), an `async` function will only return a `Promise` object instead of value. To access the response of `Promise`, you have to use `.then()`method or `await` which can return the resulting object of Promise is instead of Promise itself.
To change variables from `await`, you have access and change the variable you want to assign within the async function instead of return from it.

```js
//Save response on a variable
var globalData;
const asyncExample = async () =>{
    try {
        const data = await axios(users);
        globalData = data; // this will change globalData
        console.log(data); //200
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
asyncExample();
```

But if you do this, you may get an undefined output.

```js
asyncExample();
console.log(globalData) //undefined
```

Since `asyncExample()` is an `async` function, when `console.log` is called, `asyncExample()` has not finished yet, so `globalData` is still not assigned. The following code will call `console.log` after `asyncExample()` was done.

```js
const show = async () => {
    await asyncExample();
    console.log(globalData);
}
show();
```

Comment: …and of course you shouldn't use `globalData` at all, but rather have `asyncExample` **return** the value (fulfill the promise with it)

Comment: change `globalData = data`  to `return data` and `await asyncExample(); to `let globalData = await asyncExample();`

Answer (score -3):

Because the events are happening asynchronously you need to tie in a callback/promise. I'm going to assume it returns a promise.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const users = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

const asyncExample = async () =>{
    try {
        const data = await axios(users);
        console.log(data); //200
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

//Save response on a variable
const globalData = asyncExample().then( (success, err) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err); }
  console.log(success)
}
```

Comment: *"I'm going to assume it returns a promise"* No assumption necessary. It's an `async` function. By definition, it returns a promise. But there's no good reason to answer a question with a basic misstatement of fact (that `globalData` remains `undefined`, which it won't with the code in the question) until/unless the OP clarifies.

Comment: `asyncExample` doesn't return anything.  What do you expect the `console.log(success)` line to log? It will log `undefined`. The OP needs to `return` the `data` from that function.

Comment: Also note that your `then` callback is written as though it were a NodeJS callback (but backward). A true `then` callback never receives more than one parameter.

Answer (score -4):

Just use a callback/promise (cascading programming):

```
axios(users).then(function(response) {
    const globalData = response;
    console.log(globalData) 
});
```

Comment: I was writing my answer on mobile when the answer above was submitted and I didn't see it. I didn't copy it. Sorry for the misunderstanding.