# Assign async function result to variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm getting a firestore collection with its documents id merged with the docs data, like this:

```
async function getUsers() {
    const users = [];
    fb_db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = { ...doc.data(), ...{ id: doc.id }};
            if ( data.userid !== undefined && data.userid.length > 0 ) users.push(data);
        });
        return users;
    });
}

//this is the other question's solution
const asyncExample = async () => {
    const result = await getUsers()
    return result
}
```

As far as I understand, I'm supposed to add async to the getUsers function, tough obviously don't fully understand why

I want to get the result into a variable, I've tried to implement  [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327559/save-async-await-response-on-a-variable)  solution but I can't get it to work.

I've tried this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    someFunction();

    // this doesn't log anything but undefined
    ;(async () => {
        const users = await asyncExample()
        console.log(users)
    })()

    //obviously this doesn't work either, it just logs a promise
    the_users = getUsers();
    console.log(the_users);

    //[THIS SCOPE]
});
```

What I want is to have a variable containing the users (on //[THIS SCOPE]), then to loop the values and do 'some stuff'

Comment: You don't return anything from `getUsers()`. It should be `return fb_db.collection(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract the async process out into a independent function.

```
async function getQuerySnapshot() {
  return fb_db.collection("users").get(); // here return a promise
}

async function getUsers() {
  const querySnapshot = await getQuerySnapshot();
  const users = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = { ...doc.data(), ...{ id: doc.id }};
      if ( data.userid !== undefined && data.userid.length > 0 ) users.push(data);
  });
  // variable users is the value you want to get
  return users;
}
```

May it can help you.

Comment: I have no idea why, but separating the functions like you described made it work.
This
;(async () => {
        const users = await asyncExample()
        console.log(users)
    })()

now works, care to explain why?

Comment: @AlanVelasco Because, like I said, you didn't return anything from the function before. This one does. There's no point in separating the functions though.

Comment: @GuyIncognito If you don't extract async out, then how to directly return a promised value, as above? My only method is to use callback to handle the fetched users.

Comment: @GuyIncognito, I'm still confused, because you say I didn't return anything from getUsers(), but I do, there's a "return users;" line.

Comment: @fengxh `const querySnapshot = await fb_db.collection("users").get();` is exactly the same as what you have.

Comment: @AlanVelasco because your original async function returns nothing but undefined. I recommand you to read more tutorials/guidebook about `async`

Comment: @AlanVelasco That returns from the inner `then` callback, not from the actual function.

Comment: @GuyIncognito oh, thanks. It's unnecessary to make an additional async function, just a one-line-await code.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I think I know whay you mean. `const querySnapshot = await fb_db.collection("users").get();` should have been there first instead of doing `then`. I'll keep reading about it, but thanks.

Comment: @AlanVelasco aha, the `return` you said is just returned from the `then` callback, not the outer function `getUsers`. If you remain confused, you need to learn more basis about javascript. Work hard.