# react native : what is the way to send data from promise function into const? got some error while try console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, promise

[image]
what is the way to send the data from "Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table " promise function
into variable const data ?
i need only the "Zone_Name".

this data is an list of objects and they looks like this :
[{"Zone_ID":66,"Zone_Name":"Herzel"},{"Zone_ID":0123,"Zone_Name":"Zelda"}]

```
async Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table() {
    const Zone_Names = [];
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'SELECT Successor_Zones FROM tblUserConnectResponseData',
          [],
          (_, result) => {
            var len = result.rows.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              let row = result.rows.item(i);
              // console.log();
              const { Successor_Zones } = row;
              Zone_Names.push({
                Successor_Zones,
              });
            }
            resolve({
              isAny: true,
              Zone_Names: row,
            });
          },
          (_, err) => {
            reject(err);
          }
        );
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

i add button like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ activeIndex: 0 });
                    this.Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table.then((result) => {
                      console.log(result);
                    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
                  }}
                  activeOpacity={1}
                  style={
                    this.state.activeIndex === 0
                      ? styles.button
                      : styles.button2
                  }
                >
                  <Text style={styles.textButton}>list of places</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327559/save-async-await-response-on-a-variable?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i dont understand the example there , can u show me in my code what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration

```
async Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table() {
```

Call

```
this.Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table.then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: i add button with your call example and its say "cant find variable: Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table" why its like that ?

Comment: Because it looks like you're using class components. I updated my answer but i suggest you to learn react. You clearly have gaps with

Comment: i edit my question again as u said but get an error : this2.Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table is not a function...its says its undefined

Comment: As i said, you need to learn react. Your component must be made in a wrong way. Clearly a context error

Comment: can u show me works example with component that should work ? just add button with my function and i will see whats wrong in my way

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [zoneNames, setZoneNames] = useState();

  const Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table = () => {
    let Zone_Names = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction(tx => {
        // ...
      });
    });
  };
```

And then

```
Get_Successor_Zones_From_Table.then(data => setZoneNames(data));
```

Comment: can u help me please ? i edit my question but its not works  for me , u want i send my component ?