# error: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error "await is only valid in async function". Does anyone know where can be a problem?

```
$(document).ready(() => {

const getIso = async (latitude, longitude) => {

        let newIso = await $.ajax({
            url: `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`,
            lat: latitude,
            lon: longitude,
            datatype: 'jsonv2',
        });
        const iso = newIso.address.country_code;
        console.log(iso); // workds
        return newIso;
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        getIso(latitude, longitude);
    });

    let lol = await getIso();
    console.log(lol);

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save Async/Await response on a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327559/save-async-await-response-on-a-variable)

Comment: @pilchard I still dont know how to use it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is comming from line:

```js
let lol = await getIso();
```

because this line is inside this function:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
```

which is not an async function.

[await is a reserved word that only works inside async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_await_keyword)

Comment: I tried to put code in another async function but it didn't work. Is there some way to console.log it outside of each function?

Comment: You can change the first line of code to `$(document).ready(async () => {` so it will be async, and the await will work @Pulman3

Comment: Now it throws an error that  latitude a longitude is undefined

Comment: So the first error was solved, please mark the question as answered. Now this error is telling that you should pass two parameters "latitude" and "longitude" when calling `let lol = await getIso();` should be `let lol = await getIso(latitudeValue, longitudeValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Make your onready function async

```js
$(document).ready(async () => {

const getIso = async (latitude, longitude) => {

        let newIso = await $.ajax({
            url: `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`,
            lat: latitude,
            lon: longitude,
            datatype: 'jsonv2',
        });
        const iso = newIso.address.country_code;
        console.log(iso); // workds
        return newIso;
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        getIso(latitude, longitude);
    });

    let lol = await getIso();
    console.log(lol);

});
```

Comment: This throws me an error Failed to load resource: the server.

Comment: This new error is probably unrelated to the original issue. @Pulman3