# Accessing variables from Javascript async function for sorting

Tags: javascript, async-await

How should I extract a variable, for example "total_lots" from the async function below to be used in another function (for sorting purposes)? This code is part of a .js-.html-.css stack. Thanks :)

```
async function getData() {
        try{
            const response = await fetch ("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability");
            if (response.ok){
                const data = await response.json();
                const carparkData = data.items[0].carpark_data;          
    
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable")
                for (var i = 0; i < carparkData.length; i++){
                    const carparkNum = carparkData[i].carpark_number
                    console.log(carparkNum)
                    var row = `<tr>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_number}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].update_datetime}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lots_available}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lot_type}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots}</td>
                              </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row
                }
            } 
            throw new Error("Request failed");
        } 
            catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you just not returning it from the function, or storing it as a global variable?

Comment: You can just return it. But in that case I would suggest to separate data fetching from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I've Changed for loop condition to loop only 10 times for a better performance for the sake of this example you can always change it back to normal.

**Way 1:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="myTable">
    </table>

    <pre id="result"></pre>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    async function getData() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability");
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                const carparkData = data.items[0].carpark_data;

                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                // Making Blank array in order to push datas later
                let totalLotsArray = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // I've Changed array length to show the first 10 results for better performance.
                    const carparkNum = carparkData[i].carpark_number
                    console.log(carparkNum)
                    var row = `<tr>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_number}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].update_datetime}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lots_available}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lot_type}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots}</td>
                              </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row
                    // Pushing wanted Data to an array
                    totalLotsArray.push(carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots);
                }
                // Returning Array
                return totalLotsArray
            }
            throw new Error("Request failed");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    // Changing the way we call getData()
    getData().then(totalLots => console.log("extracted variable: ", totalLots));
</script>
```

**Way 2:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="myTable">
    </table>

    <pre id="result"></pre>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    let exportedTotalLots = null;
    async function getData() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability");
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                const carparkData = data.items[0].carpark_data;

                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                // Making Blank array in order to push datas later
                let totalLotsArray = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // I've Changed array length to show the first 10 results for better performance.
                    const carparkNum = carparkData[i].carpark_number
                    console.log(carparkNum)
                    var row = `<tr>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_number}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].update_datetime}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lots_available}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lot_type}</td>
                                    <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots}</td>
                              </tr>`
                    table.innerHTML += row
                    // Pushing wanted Data to an array
                    totalLotsArray.push(carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots);
                }
                // modifiying pre-defined variable then call a function to put the results in a DOM!
                exportedTotalLots = totalLotsArray;
                fetched()
            }
            throw new Error("Request failed");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    getData();
    function fetched(){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = exportedTotalLots
    }
</script>
```

**Way 3:**
It is written in NodeJS, thought it might help.

> [Save Async/Await response on a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327559/save-async-await-response-on-a-variable)

**Way 4:**

Similar to Way 1 You can use Promises(). let me know if you want a code snippet for this method.

> Documentation:  https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=JavaScript&docset_name=JavaScript&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/promise-2.html&platform=javascript&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/promise

Comment: @rach then upvote and mark it as an answer

Answer (score -1):

```js
async function getData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability');
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      const carparkData = data.items[0].carpark_data;
      render(carparkData);
      
      return {
        carparkData,
      };
    }
    throw new Error('Request failed');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function render(carparkData) {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  for (var i = 0; i < carparkData.length; i++) {
    const carparkNum = carparkData[i].carpark_number;
    console.log(carparkNum);
    var row = `<tr>
                        <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_number}</td>
                        <td>${carparkData[i].update_datetime}</td>
                        <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lots_available}</td>
                        <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].lot_type}</td>
                        <td>${carparkData[i].carpark_info[0].total_lots}</td>
                    </tr>`;
    table.innerHTML += row;
  }
}
```